# Laravel foreaching random models

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-7, seed

I am making seeders for a M:M relation where I would like to attach 1 `Widget` to `WorkspaceItem` in 90% of cases, other 5% 2, last 5% 3.

```
$widgets = Widget::all();
$workspaceItems = WorkspaceItem::all();

foreach ($workspaceItems as $workspaceItem) {
    $numberBetween = $faker->numberBetween(0, 100);

    if ($numberBetween > 95) {
        $widgetsToSeed = $widgets->random(3);
    } else if ($numberBetween > 90 && $numberBetween <= 95) {
        $widgetsToSeed = $widgets->random(2);
    } else {
        $widgetsToSeed = $widgets->random();
    }

    foreach ($widgetsToSeed as $widget) {
        $workspaceItem->widgets()->attach($widget->id, [...]);
    }
}
```

**Note**: I can't use `sync()` because I have additional properties for pivot table.

If I `dd($widgetsToSeed)`, I indeed get random widgets. But as soon as it enters the loop and I `dd($widget)` I don't get the model, but just `true`. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Try with `$widgetsToSeed->all() as $widget` in foreach

Comment: This loads all widgets from the DB, not just the picked random ones

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should be able to just do:

```
$workspaceItem->widgets()->saveMany($widgetsToSeed);
```

And by that you don't even need the last `foreach` loop. To always receive a collection (even with only one element), you can also add `random(1)` in your last `else` statement. With some minor simplifications it might look like this:

```
foreach ($workspaceItems as $workspaceItem) {
    $numberBetween = $faker->numberBetween(0, 100);

    if ($numberBetween > 95) {
        $widgetsToSeed = $widgets->random(3);
    } else if ($numberBetween > 90) {
        $widgetsToSeed = $widgets->random(2);
    } else {
        $widgetsToSeed = $widgets->random(1);
    }

    $workspaceItem->widgets()->saveMany($widgetsToSeed);
}
```

Comment: `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::save() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, bool given` Unfortunately it breaks as well for some reason...

Comment: in your last if statement add random(1) to also get a collection. Does that it?

Comment: Yes! Great, it's working now. Edit the answer so I can accept it